# Library for Visualizing Text within a Graph

Tags: text, data-visualization, visualization, graph-visualization

I am trying to visualize text for concepts that are related by a graph. Many programs visualize text in relatively small, sparse circular nodes. This makes it difficult to view textual data. I would like to use a library that provides a visualization similar to the image below. What is the program or programming library that created this image?

[image]

Comment: This may be a D3 Hierarchical Tree Diagram.

Answer (score 1):

This graph can be achieved using D3.js Hierarchical Tree Diagram. In particular, see:

D3 - Hierarchy:
https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md

Tidy Tree:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/tidy-tree
[image]

Indented Tree:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/indented-tree
[image]